# Python: Why do these lines of code display different values?

Tags: python, list

I am relatively new to coding and python and I am trying to wrap my head round some concepts. One I am struggling on is the split() function and why these two pieces of code produce two different outputs

```
y = ["hello\n", "world\n", "python\n"]
x = [line.strip() for line in y]
print(x)
```

and

```
y = ["hello\n", "world\n", "python\n"]
for line in y:
    x = [line.strip()]
print(x)
```

The first piece of code produces an output of

```
['hello', 'world', 'python']
```

Whilst the second produces

```
['python']
```

Does anyone know why this is, as to me they should do the same thing by both producing an output of

```
['python']
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know why this is, as to me they should do the same thing by both producing an output of ['python'].

Your first code uses [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which is used to create a sequence. 
It provides a concise way to create lists or sequence of elements.

Your second code is basically using a for loop just to get the last element of list `y`. `for` loop is used if you want to iterate through a sequence. However, you are also overwriting the variable `x` in each of your iteration and hence, when you come out of for loop, it will be pointing to the last element (i.e., ['python']). Try this:

```
for line in y:
    x = [line.strip()]
    print(x)
```

If you just want the last element of your list `y` and strip() it, you can also do that via:

```
x = [ y[-1].strip() ]
```

OR

If you want the list, then use your first code.

**MORE INFORMATION**

If you can change your second code to:

```
x = [ ]
y = ["hello\n", "world\n", "python\n"]
for line in y:
    x.append(line.strip())
print(x)
```

Then both will print same output (i.e., `['hello', 'world', 'python']`).

Answer (score 3):

In the second one you overwrite `x` for each loop iteration, and you only see `x`'s value from the last iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The first version of your code is using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), where you accumulate the results of processing each element in an output list that contains all the elements.

Whereas in the second version, you process one element at a time inside the loop, saving the result in a single-element list and overwriting the previous value, so when you exit the loop the variable will contain the last element that was processed.

Answer (score 1):

`x = [line.strip()]` creates a new list with a single element each time you iterate through the loop. You can more easily see what is happening by moving the `print()` inside the loop:

```
y = ["hello\n", "world\n", "python\n"]
for line in y:
    x = [line.strip()]
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

in your first case:

```
y = ["hello\n", "world\n", "python\n"]
x = [line.strip() for line in y]
print(x)
```

you are using a list comprehension to define your variable `x` by iterating over all the elements from `y` and keeping them into a new list, this line is equivalent with:

```
x = []
for line in y:
    x.append(line.strip)
```

in your second case:

```
y = ["hello\n", "world\n", "python\n"]
for line in y:
    x = [line.strip()]
print(x)
```

you are  assigning to the same variable `x` a different value on each iteration of the `for` loop this means that your variable `x` will end to have the last value from your list `y` (with `str.strip` applied)

---

another  nice way to achieve your desired output:

```
list(map(str.strip, y))
```